# how to save texts that has been written in an entry in python

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Smzk2.png)

when i write in the execution's entry i want this to be saved in another text file
how ?
and this is my code

```
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
label1=ttk.Label(root,text="Type your message : ",font="classic")
label1.pack()
entry1=ttk.Entry(root,width=70)
entry1.pack()
button=ttk.Button(root,text="Send",padding=7,cursor="hand2")
button.pack()
def Bclick () :
    entry1.delete(0,END)
    print("sent")
button.config(command=Bclick)
file = input("yo :")
root.mainloop()
with open('text','w') as myfile : 
    myfile.write(file)
```

Comment: It is not recommended to call console `input()` in a GUI application.  What is the purpose of the line `file = input("yo :")` actually? You can use `entry1.get()` to get the input text in the entry box and save the input text to file since you already have code of saving file.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "when i write in the execution's entry i want this to be saved in another text file" - I can't understand this, first off because "write in the execution's entry" doesn't make sense, and second because the code already will write whatever was provided for the `input`, and there is no other code that does anything with that input.

Answer (score 0):

To get the value from an `Entry` widget, you need to use its `get` method, e.g.,

```
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
label1 = ttk.Label(root, text="Type your message : ", font="classic")
label1.pack()
entry1 = ttk.Entry(root, width=70)
entry1.pack()
button = ttk.Button(root, text="Send", padding=7, cursor="hand2")
button.pack()

def Bclick():
    entryvalue = entry1.get()  # get what's in the Entry widget before clearing it
    entry1.delete(0,END)
    print("sent")

    # write the value to a file
    with open("text", "w") as myfile:
        myfile.write(entryvalue)  # write it to your file


button.config(command=Bclick)
#file = input("yo :")  # not sure what this was for, so I've commented it out

root.mainloop()
```

After this, your file `text` should contain whatever you entered into the `Entry` box.

Comment: Have you tested your code? When the file saving code is executed, `entryvalue` is undefined. You need to put the file saving code inside `Bclick()`.

Comment: You're right, I tested it with the `root.mainloop()` before the writing to file, then moved it in my answer. I've switched it back, but , as you suggest, it would be better to just put the saving code inside the `Bclick` function and avoid any use of globals.

Comment: I've move the saving part into `Bclick`.

Comment: Matt pitkin it works!! you're the bestt tyy

Answer (score 0):

What your current code is doing is building the interface then it collects input through the terminal and writes it to a file, and then finally it displays the window to the user.

What you want to do instead is inside of your buttons callback method, collect the input from the `Entry` widget, and save whatever it contains in the your buttons callback.

```
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *

filename = "MyTextFile.txt"

root = Tk()
label1=ttk.Label(root,text="Type your message : ",font="classic")
label1.pack()

entry1=ttk.Entry(root,width=70)
entry1.pack()

button=ttk.Button(root,text="Send",padding=7,cursor="hand2")
button.pack()

def Bclick():
    text = entry1.get()
    with open(filename, "wt") as fd:
        fd.write(text)
    entry1.delete(0,END)
    print("sent")

button.config(command=Bclick)

root.mainloop()
```